# Is this a correct way of sorting by title, position and then order by using a Comparator?

Tags: java, sorting, comparator

Consider this class.

```
public class DynamicField implements Comparable<DynamicField> {
    String title;
    int position;
    int order;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(DynamicField o) {
        if(position < o.position) 
            return -1;
        if(position > o.position)
            return 1;

        if(order < o.order)
            return -1;
        if(order > o.order)
            return 1;

        return title.compareTo(o.title);

    }
}
```

Is the compareTo method correct if I want to sort by title, position and then order?

Comment: The right way to answer your question is to use Junit to write a short test case. The compareTo as written will sort on position, order, and then title in that order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you're making comparisons in an incorrect order.  Rearranging comparisons order would make it work:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(DynamicField o) {
    int c = title.compareTo(o.title);
    if (c != 0)
      return c;
    if(position < o.position) 
        return -1;
    if(position > o.position)
        return 1;
    if(order < o.order)
        return -1;
    if(order > o.order)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will accept this answer since it was the most readable

Comment: @Shervin  you should also consider the quality :-)

Comment: And correctness, e.g. avoiding the possibility of overflow. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

No,Try this code
**Updated**

```
  public class DynamicField implements Comparable<DynamicField> {
        String title;
        int position;
        int order;

        @Override
        public int compareTo(DynamicField o) {
            int result = title.compareTo(o.title);
            if(result != 0) {}             
            else if(position != o.position)
                result = position-o.position;
            else if(order != o.order)
                result = order- o.order;

            return result;

        }
    }
```

Comment: What if `title.compareTo(o.title) == 0`, `position < o.position` and `order > o.order`.  Your method will return `0`.

Comment: @Sheldon L. Cooper   Thanks I missed that scenario updated the code

Answer (score 0):

This is actually the same as @org.life.java's answer. You might find this one more palatable, though.

```
@Override
public int compareTo() {
    int result = title.compareTo(o.title);
    if (result == 0)
        result = position - o.position;
    if (result == 0)
        result = order - o.order;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: What if the position or order is a negative value? What happens then? I think then your order of position and order will be reversed

Comment: Nope, this should give you the same answer as @Sheldon's. The only problem I can see is an overflow here, if, say, position is close to 2^31 (2 to the power 31) and o.position is close to -2^31. But if position and order values range, for instance, from -2^30 to 2^30, then this is ok.